# Модификатор Boolean создает дубликат

Tags: blender

Я смотрел другие вопросы на эту тему и там преимущественно речь о "сложных" фигурах, но как можно накосячить с двумя кубами, которые я пытаюсь объединить.[image: Уже можно увидеть мурашки на кубе][image: Применяем и получаем третий куб]

Answer (score 0):

А в чем собственно вопрос? Модификатор это вещь, которая модифицирует один объект, работает только с одним объектом, а не с двумя или несколькими. Если вы не понимаете, что такое модификатор, почему вы рассуждаете о том, как он должен работать? Вам нужна операция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы, кажется, вообще не поняли вопроса, модификатор Boolean СОЗДАЕТ ДУБЛИКАТЫ - ЭТО В ПРИНЦИПЕ НЕ ЕГО ЗАДАЧА, с какой стати это происходит, вот в чем вопрос, я даже над кубами банальные операции без геморроя не могу провести.

Comment: а где дубликаты? Как было два объекта, так и осталось два. Давайте переформулируем вопрос - "Почему модификатор Boolean не удаляет объекты при применении модификатора". Ну, например, потому, что объект который вы ходите удалить, может, например, использоваться в других модификаторах.

Comment: Это уже походит на цирк, опыт показывает, что вопросы я нормально задавать умею, остается два варианта, либо я совсем дурак и не понимаю, как должен работать этот модификатор и какого результата ожидать, либо дурак кто-то другой... Что значит «как было два объекта, так и осталось два»? Было два, должен стать один, я разве не объединение использую? Откуда взялся дубликат куба? О каких дополнительных модификаторах идет речь? Я пример до тупости упростил: вы открываете блендер, у вас уже есть куб, я создаю второй куб и добавляю ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ модификатор boolean и ставлю в поле object второй куб.

Comment: Модификатор это не операция. Поймите же это наконец. Модификатор изменяет один объект и только один